# How to arm a drone using Dronkit-Python without required the controller to be on?

Tags: dronekit-python

I am trying to arm it using Dronkit-Python and I am able to get it to arm properly through code, however, it requires the controller to be on.

Is there anyway to bypass this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the RC Controller (not the flight controller), you'll need to turn off the radio failsafe (FS_THR_ENABLE).